# Angular Function Call in HTML

Tags: angular

I have an Angular Project and in one component i want to show data by calling a function to the corresponding component.ts.

For example (very simplified)

```
<div *ngFor="let article of article">
  <h1>{{getTitle(article)}}</h1>
</div>
```

If i check a console.log in the getTitle function there are a lot of logs, thus the function gets triggerd due to angular events to rerender i would say.

Now i am thinking maybe it is not the best idea to do it in this way? Assumed lot of data in a ngfor loop are shown. What do you think?

Comment: Definitely not the way to do it. In your controller, set a title property on the articles when the list changes. Function calls In template are almost universally bad

Comment: you are already using ngfor which means you are iterating an array of I assume objects. shouldn't your title be there?

Comment: yea it is there, it was just a very simplified example. In praxis i do calculations there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this.

**component.ts:**

```
class Article
{
title:string
author:string
}
articles=[
new Article("title1","author1"),
new Article("title2","author2")
];
```

**component.html:**

```
<div *ngFor="let article of article">
  <h1>{{article.title}}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: yes your data should be set up to include title as part of your data. don't try calling a function from your html. that is never a good idea.

Comment: can you also say why its a bad idea, just getting trouble with performance or are there other reasons?

Comment: Accept the answer if it satisfied you. Thank you.

Comment: @Dalitos If you are working on long list of objects, the function has to run each time. In this method all those resources are saved.